# Получение неверного элемента по индексу из коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

Почему я получаю элемент со значением 57, хотя должен получить 23. Вроде в цикле забираю элемент под 3 индексом. Даже если я поставлю совершенно другое значение для int i, например 2, то выдаст ту же ошибку.

```java
public static List<Integer> task2(Integer... array) {
        List<Integer> myArrays = Arrays.asList(array);
        for (int i = 3; i < myArrays.size(); i++) {
            if (myArrays.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
                myArrays.set(i, myArrays.get(i) + 1);
            }
        }
        return myArrays;
    }
```

```java
@Test
    void task2() {
        assertIterableEquals(
                Arrays.asList(57, 23, 43, 95, 13),
                Lesson10_CollectionsLists.task2(23, 15, 1, 56, 22, 42, 95, 13, 9)
        );
```

```java
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: iterable contents differ at index [0], expected: <57> but was: <23>
```

P.S. По заданию я должен увеличить все четные числа на 1 и вернуть с 3 по 7 элементы.

Comment: Читайте задание. Судя по тесту в вашей коллекции должно остаться 5 значений. А вы только меняете четные элементы на нечетные. Тест сравнивает первые элементы двух коллекций и говорит вам что они не совпадают

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: а возвращаете весь массив, вы проверку на четность начинаете с 3 элемента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вроде в цикле забираю элемент под 3 индексом. Даже если я поставлю совершенно другое значение для int i, например 2, то выдаст ту же ошибку.

Вы не "Забираете элемент под 3 индексом", а итерируетесь по списку начиная с 3 индекса. После чего вы увеличиваете на 1 все четные числа, но при этом возвращаете весь список, а не то, что описано в задание, то есть:

> По заданию я должен увеличить все четные числа на 1 и **вернуть с 3 по 7 элементы**

для того что бы вернуть элементы с 3 по 7 вам стоит использовать метод [subList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)
и прошу учесть, последний индекс не включается в "срез".

Ну и естественно, стоит рассмотреть случай когда размер списка меньше 8, что бы избежать ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
public static List<Integer> task2(Integer... array) {
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 3; i < 8; i++) {
        res.add(array[i] % 2 == 0 ? array[i] + 1 : array[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Что произойдет, если в ``array`` больше восьми элементов?

Comment: Массивы ни к чему.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, согласен, поправил

Comment: А если меньше восьми? :)

Comment: @Эникейщик это можно обрабатывать по разному. Можно проверить длину массива сначала и выкинуть IllegalArgumentException, Можно проверять длину массива и выдавать с 3 знака по конец массива. Тут еще можно проверить вдруг он меньше 4 символов или вообще null, а так же передавать индексы начала и окончания как параметры... я писал под конкретный тест, надеюсь дальше автор сообразит :)